# How to solve integer program using MIR inequalities?

Tags: inequality

How do you solve an integer program using Mixed Integer Rounding inequailities? Since it's a rounding inequality I am confused how to approach this when the coefficients of the problem are all integers.

The problem is

$\texttt{max} \ \ 5*x_1+9*x_2+23*x_3-4*s$

$\texttt{s.t.} \ \ 2*x_1+3*x_2+9*x_3\leq 32-s$

$x_1,x_2,x_3$ are integers.

$s \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Presumably, you have to first solve the IP as an LP and apply the rounding on the resulting constraints which will include constraints with non-integer coefficients.

Comment: Why you don´t post your program ?

Comment: The program is max{5*x1+9*x2+23*x3-4*s:2*x1+3*x2+9*x3<=32-s} x1,x2,x3 are integers and s is a real number

Comment: @miat123 You can use Branch and Bound to solve the problem.